# How can I properly import TSX files using relative paths?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have a React/Typescript/webpack project.

Everything works fine, except that when I import a 'tsx' file I need to supply the entire path or it will fail to compile.

I want to just write:

```
import './styles.less';
import { TestComponent } from './TestComponent.tsx';
```

While the less import works fine, the tsx import fails unless I write:

```
import './styles.less';
import { TestComponent } from '@src/components/TestComponent.tsx';
```

Comment: What about `@./TestComponent.tsx`?

Comment: The path should be relative to the current file. `'./TestComponent.tsx'` should work just fine if your including component is in `components`.

Comment: Otherwise, you have to zoom back 1 level *to* `components`.

Comment: You can't import a `.ts` or `.tsx` file explicitly. Either import `'./TestComponent'`, letting your tools determine the extension, or import `'./TestComponent.jsx'`.

Comment: Sigh. So this is some weird webpack/VS Code issue. The IDE is fine with `import { TestComponent } from './TestComponent'`, but webpack is not - I get "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve  './TestComponent'". And I do have "tsx" in my webpack config here:  resolve: {
      extensions: [
        '.webpack.js',
        '.web.js',
        '.js',
        '.ts',
        '.tsx'
      ]